# Dart Non-Reentrant Async Lock

Tags: thread-safety, locking, dart, flutter

This class synchronizes access to an async resource. If `retainFutureErrors` is false, it will keep retrying until there is a success. Otherwise, the `locked` method will return a `Future` with an error. This will form the basis of getting dependencies in [ioc_container](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/ioc_container/blob/main/lib/ioc_container.dart) in the next version. By default, the container should not allow reentrancy unless there is an error, and the container should not store a Future that has an error.

````dart
import 'dart:async';

/// A lock that ensures that only one async function executes at a time.
class AsyncLock<T> {
  /// Creates a new [AsyncLock].
  AsyncLock({this.retainFutureErrors = false});

  Completer<T>? _completer;

  /// Whether to retain errors or allow reentrancy until the Future completes 
  /// successfully.
  final bool retainFutureErrors;

  /// Executes the given [function] and returns the value, but ensures that 
  /// only one async function executes at a time.
  Future<T> locked(FutureOr<T> Function() function) async =>
      _completer?.future ?? _executeFunction(function);

  /// Creates a new [Completer], executes the given [function] and
  /// returns the value.
  Future<T> _executeFunction(FutureOr<T> Function() function) async {
    _completer = Completer<T>();
    try {
      final result = await function();
      _completer!.complete(result);
      return result;
      // ignore: avoid_catches_without_on_clauses
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      if (retainFutureErrors) {
        _completer!.completeError(error, stackTrace);
      } else {
        _completer = null;
      }
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```
````

Answer (score 3):

Error Handling: The locked method will retry indefinitely if retainFutureErrors is set to false and the future fails. A timeout mechanism or a cap on the number of retries would be preferable in this situation because it could result in an infinite loop. Additionally, when the Completer instance is nullified in the catch block, it is not clear why this is done.

Threading: While the code uses a Completer to ensure that only one async function executes at a time, it is not clear how this will work with multiple isolates or threads.

Here are some tests:

````
import 'dart:async';

/// A lock that ensures that only one async function executes at a time.
class AsyncLock<T> {
  /// Creates a new [AsyncLock].
  AsyncLock({this.retainFutureErrors = false});

  Completer<T>? _completer;

  /// Whether to retain errors or allow reentrancy until the Future completes 
  /// successfully.
  final bool retainFutureErrors;

  /// Executes the given [function] and returns the value, but ensures that 
  /// only one async function executes at a time.
  Future<T> locked(FutureOr<T> Function() function) async =>
      _completer?.future ?? _executeFunction(function);

  /// Creates a new [Completer], executes the given [function] and
  /// returns the value.
  Future<T> _executeFunction(FutureOr<T> Function() function) async {
    _completer = Completer<T>();
    try {
      final result = await function();
      _completer!.complete(result);
      return result;
      // ignore: avoid_catches_without_on_clauses
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      if (retainFutureErrors) {
        _completer!.completeError(error, stackTrace);
      } else {
        _completer = null;
      }
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}

class AsyncLockReentryError implements Exception {
  @override
  String toString() => 'AsyncLockReentryError: Cannot re-enter locked function.';
}


void main() {
  group('AsyncLock', () {
    test('should execute function when lock is available', () async {
      final asyncLock = AsyncLock<int>();
      final result = await asyncLock.locked(() => Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () => 1));
      expect(result, equals(1));
    });

    test('should execute multiple functions in sequence', () async {
      final asyncLock = AsyncLock<int>();
      final firstResult = await asyncLock.locked(() => Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () => 1));
      expect(firstResult, equals(1));
      final secondResult = await asyncLock.locked(() => Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () => 2));
      expect(secondResult, equals(2));
    });

    test('should execute function after previous lock completes', () async {
      final asyncLock = AsyncLock<int>();
      final firstResult = await asyncLock.locked(() => Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () => 1));
      expect(firstResult, equals(1));
      final secondResult = await asyncLock.locked(() => Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () => 2));
      expect(secondResult, equals(2));
      final thirdResult = await asyncLock.locked(() => Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () => 3));
      expect(thirdResult, equals(3));
    });

    test('should execute function after previous lock completes even with errors', () async {
      final asyncLock = AsyncLock<int>(retainFutureErrors: true);
      final firstResult = await asyncLock.locked(() => Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () => 1));
      expect(firstResult, equals(1));
      await expectLater(
        asyncLock.locked(() => Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () => throw Exception('error'))),
        throwsA(isA<Exception>()),
      );
      final thirdResult = await asyncLock.locked(() => Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () => 3));
      expect(thirdResult, equals(3));
    });

    test('should throw error when retainFutureErrors is false', () async {
      final asyncLock = AsyncLock<int>();
      final future = asyncLock.locked(() => Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () => throw Exception('error')));
      await expectLater(future, throwsA(isA<Exception>()));
    });

    test('should return result with error when retainFutureErrors is true', () async {
      final asyncLock = AsyncLock<int>(retainFutureErrors: true);
      final future = asyncLock.locked(() => Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () => throw Exception('error')));
      await expectLater(future, throwsA(isA<Exception>()));
      await expectLater(future.catchError((e) => e), isA<Exception>());
    });

    test('should not allow reentrancy by default', () async {
      final asyncLock = AsyncLock<int>();
      final future = asyncLock.locked(() => asyncLock.locked(() => Future.value()));
      await expectLater(future, throwsA(isA<AsyncLockReentryError>()));
    });

    test('should allow reentrancy if there is an error', () async {
      final asyncLock = AsyncLock<int>(retainFutureErrors: true);
      final future = asyncLock.locked(() => asyncLock.locked(() => Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () => throw Exception('error'))));
     


      });
  });
}```
````

Comment: Question: how would this work across isolates? Dart doesn't allow sharing of resources across isolates so what kind of scenario would cause an issue?

Comment: I think these tests expose that this class is not a complete solution and cannot be used as a generic lock. I think it will only work in specific scenarios. This test: should execute multiple functions in sequence proves that.

Comment: I updated the code accordingly, but unfortunately, this breaks compilation on several of your tests

Comment: Sending messages between isolates allows you to still talk to each other. To send and receive messages between isolates, for instance, you can use the SendPort and ReceivePort classes. Since isolates cannot directly access each other's resources, this enables you to share information and plan actions between them.

Comment: which approach did you use in your update

Comment: Sorry, the changed got rolled back. Retiring this question.

Comment: This is a great review - identifying a lurking bug is the best possible outcome.  @Christian, if you improve the code, please post the new code for review (in a new question) and include a link to this one so that reviewers can understand that aspect of the design.  We don't "retire" answered questions here, but I do recommend you _accept_ this answer to indicate that you're not looking for further review of this version.

Comment: I tried to post the new code and they rolled it back @TobySpeight

Comment: @Christian, I think you misunderstood: you tried to _edit_ this question here, but that's not the right way to do it (it can cause the answers to look nonsensical).  You should [_ask a new question_](/questions/ask) instead.  You can include a link that points to this question to help give readers the context.  Is that helpful?

Comment: I can neither close or delete the question so it's here for posterity